# cb is not a function when trying to use a different parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have s3 server access logs in a bucket and I'm trying to get them to ElasticSearch service on AWS with a lambda function.

[The example lambda function](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/s3_lambda_es.js) that I'm using, which uses `clf-parser` to paste apache common log files. Since I want to use [s3-log-parser](https://github.com/ifit/s3-log-parser), I have made the following changes:

```
// instead of 
var parse = require('clf-parser');
// I have
var s3logparser = require('s3-log-parser');

// instead of
var logRecord = parse(line.toString());
// I have
var logRecord = s3LogParser.parse(line.toString());`
```

and I get

```
ReferenceError: s3LogParser is not defined
```

am I calling the module wrong? I did `var s3LogParser= require('s3-log-parser');` to fix that error and now I get `TypeError: cb is not a function`

I noticed that in index.js for s3 parser there is this line : `cb(null, parsedLogs);` ... trying to figure out how to fix this callback issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the `s3-log-parser` module expects a callback and doesn't return anything from its `parse()` function even though the function is 100% synchronous. So the only way to get your parsed logs is to provide a callback function.

```
var logRecord = s3LogParser.parse(line.toString(), function (err, lines) {
  logRecord = lines
})
console.log(logRecord)
```

**Edit**

Using s3-access-log-parser instead ([example](https://runkit.com/57f5371ae47f5614002a8779/5818fa959671a70014a3a713)):

```
var s3alp = require("s3-access-log-parser")
var bogusCharacters = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(8204, 8203), 'g')
var logRecord = s3alp(line.toString().replace(bogusCharacters, ''))
```

Comment: still isn't logging to ES so I'm assuming it's not parsing correctly but the callback issue is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @tyrell_c I would recommend using [s3-access-log-parser](https://github.com/icodeforlove/s3-access-log-parser) instead considering s3-log-parser hasn't been updated in four years **and** its tests are A) broken and B) not good. You also then wouldn't have the problem with the dumb callback.

Comment: Sounds like a much better idea. I have `var s3alp= require('s3-access-log-parser'); ` and `var logRecord = s3alp(line.toString());` ... it's all good until that line. line.toString returns the string but logRecord is actually null ..

Comment: @tyrell_c can you show us what a single `line.toString()` returns? The module will return `null` if the string isn't in the correct format.

Comment: it returns access log something like this : `79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be mybucket [06/Feb/2014:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 3E57427F3EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /mybucket?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 7 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" -`

Comment: it looks aligned with the regex in the module.

Comment: It aligns with example I gave you. It doesn't with my test string ... I need to change the regex

Comment: @tyrell_c weirdly there seems to be some invisible character in the long hex string. [Here's the example when I copy and paste the example log string you provided](https://runkit.com/57f5371ae47f5614002a8779/5818f74fc3b80300148b4451). [And here it is working when you remove those weird invisible characters](https://runkit.com/57f5371ae47f5614002a8779/5818f9167f47d000133fc4b5).

Comment: I also changed the regex ad now I'm getting a nice json. Only thing is `"operation":"T"` should be `"operation":"REST.GET.REQUEST_PAYMENT"`. working on it.

Comment: @tyrell_c see the example link in my post. It seems to be parsing the operation correctly.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Must be the way "REST.GET.REQUEST_PAYMENT" is parsed. might have to specify an if statement for it.

Comment: Maybe important to note that I changed the regex for operations field to `(?:([a-z\._])+|-)` to allow for underscore.